# Getting Segmentation Fault with TinyXML

Tags: c++, xml, segmentation-fault, tinyxml

I currently have an XML file which I'm parsing using TinyXML. The top of my XML file look as so :

```
<Classroom>12
    <ClassName>name</ClassName>
    ...
</Classroom>
```

I'm attempting to access the text in ClassName. I am currently getting a segmentation fault using this:

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
doc.LoadFile(file);
TiXmlHandle  handle(&doc);

TiXmlElement * child = handle.FirstChild().FirstChild().ToElement();
cout<<child->GetText();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: for the record, my file name is correct.

Comment: Did you check that `child` is not null? What happens if you do `if(!child) std::cout << "null pointer";`.

Comment: It is coming back null. I can't figure out why still.

Comment: A call to the parent element works just fine.

Comment: @user1526283: Does calling the parent element print 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first call to FirstChild() returns a TiXmlElement representing the first `<Classroom>`
2. The second call to FirstChild() returns a TiXmlText representing the text "12"
3. TiXmlText does not override the ToElement() function, therefore using the base class's ToElement() function, which returns NULL.

You can change your code to the following:

```
TiXmlElement * child = handle.FirstChild("Classroom").FirstChild("ClassName").ToElement();
```